# Python Advance pattern to capture email address

Tags: regex, python-2.7, email-validation

I am working on a single pattern to capture correct email address address with the angular braces. 
As per the below cases, correct email address is when both the braces are provided or none 
are entered.

Correct Email address format :-

---

```
 1. <abc@gmail.co.in> , <abc@gmail.com> 
 2. abc@gmail.co.in , abc@gmail.com
```

In correct email address format :-

---

```
 1. <abc@gmail.co.in 
 2. abc@gmail.com> 
 3. <abc@gmail>  
 4. <abcgmail.com> 
 5  <abc@gmail.com>
```

Code to capture the above email address :-

'''

Capture the  email address. Allow both the opening and closing angular braces else incorrect pattern. 
'''

```
import re
# Sub pattern "(?(id)[>])" is used to compare that if the group('id') has matched then expect the closing angular brace else not. 

pattern = r'(?P<id>[<])(\w+@\w+)((\.\w+)+)(?(id)[>])'
m = re.search(pattern,email,re.I)
if m:
    print "Correct Email:",m.group()
else:
    print "Incorrect Pattern!"
```

The above code is correctly matching the case when email with angular braces and when incorrect braces are given (eg: missing opening / closing braces ).

But the pattern is not matching the case when email without angular braces are provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two regexes to match theses two types of email addresses(1, to match the email addresses which neither preceeded by `<` and nor followed by `>` symbol 2. to match the email addresses which are  preceeded by `<` and  followed by `>` symbol) . By combining the both regexes with `|` OR operator, you will get the emails which are matched by the both.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """<abc@gmail.co.in> <abc@gmail.com>   abc@gmail.co.in abc@gmail.com <abc@gmail> <abc@gmail.co.in  abc@gmail.com> """
>>> for i in re.findall(r'<\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+>|(?<!<)\b(?:\w+@\w+)(?:\.\w+)+\b(?!>)', s):
    print(i)


<abc@gmail.co.in>
<abc@gmail.com>
abc@gmail.co.in
abc@gmail.com
```

Through `re.search` function.

```
>>> s = """<abc@gmail.co.in> <abc@gmail.com> abc@gmail.co.in abc@gmail.com <abc@gmail> <abc@gmail.co.in abc@gmail.com>"""
>>> for i in s.split():
    m = re.search(r'<\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+>|(?<!<)\b(?:\w+@\w+)(?:\.\w+)+\b(?!>)', i)
    if m:
        print("Correct Email : " + m.group())
    else:
        print ("Incorrect Pattern!")


Correct Email : <abc@gmail.co.in>
Correct Email : <abc@gmail.com>
Correct Email : abc@gmail.co.in
Correct Email : abc@gmail.com
Incorrect Pattern!
Incorrect Pattern!
Incorrect Pattern!
```

[Explanation](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%28%3F%3C!%3C%29%5Cb%28%3F%3A%5Cw%2B%40%5Cw%2B%29%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cw%2B%29%2B%5Cb%28%3F!%3E%29&.submit=Explain!&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Comment: IN this pattern - (?<!<)\b(?:\w+@\w+)(?:\.\w+)+\b(?!>), could you explain two part of the regex :- 1. (?<!<)  2. (?!>)

Comment: This does work for me. But as I do not have advance level knowledge  I need some help in understanding two parts 1. (?!>) 2. (?!>). I need some basic level knowledge in understanding both these parts of the pattern.

Comment: `(?<!<)` neagative lookbehind which asserts that the match would be preceded by any character but not of `<` symbol. `(?!>)` nagative lookahead which asserts that the match would be followed by any character but not of `>` symbol.